# Jewish Life and Learning self-evaluation: how ARE you doing?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, quality-evaluation

Let's do another one of these. :)

There are lots of metrics we can use to "measure" a site, and we do, but none of them matter as much as having a healthy and happy site full of interesting questions and expert answers.

So, let's talk about site health. Specifically, *your* site health.

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from Jewish Life and Learning. Review them and take a look around the Internet as if you were trying to find answers to them. Are they interesting questions? Are the answers we have better than what Google has to offer? Are they easily found?

Upvote the corresponding post in this "thread" when our answer is better. Downvote when Google wins. If we're kinda on par with Google, just use common sense and your expertise to guide your vote. :)

Comment to let us know your thoughts... and if you need help, use our [handy dandy guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQxi7.png).

(This evaluation will close on May 4, 2012.)

Comment: The first self evaluation is here: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/836/site-self-evaluation-how-are-you-doing

Answer (score 4):

[Nursing in the bathroom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13723/nursing-in-the-bathroom)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: Result #1 on [my search terms](https://www.google.com/search?q=nurse|breastfeed+bathroom+halacha|torah|jewish|judaism) and pretty good answers. +1.

Comment: +1 I searched for *halacha nursing bathroom* and found our content at the top, followed by two other clearly on-point pages. Our content includes two answers and multiple comments, documenting and referencing multiple points of view on this issue (one of which is one of the other two pages). The other two pages each reference one point of view. Our content could stand to be improved, though, by promoting some comment material to answers.

Answer (score 4):

[Should the shaliach tzibbur check the tzitzis of a tallis given to him to daven?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13888/should-the-shaliach-tzibbur-check-the-tzitzis-of-a-tallis-given-to-him-to-daven)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: +1: [first result](https://www.google.com/search?q=talis|tallis|tallit+check|inspect+strings+chazzan|chazan|shatz+OR+%22shaliach|shliach+tzibur|tzibbur%22) and good quality.

Comment: +1 I searched *check tallit|tallis chazzan* and found our content as the second link, with none of the other links on the first page obviously pointing to this sort of issue. We have a good, well-sourced answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Product liability in halacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13770/product-liability-in-halacha)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: Very nice answer and first result on [my search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22product+liability%22+%22choshen+mishpat%22+OR+torah|halacha). +1.

Answer (score 2):

[Did the prophets practice magic?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13693/did-the-prophets-practice-magic)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: We're good, and result #3 on [my search terms](https://www.google.com/search?q=magic|kishuf+miracle|nes|nisim+difference+torah|jewish|judaism) (though #2 is also good). That counts as a +1.

Answer (score 2):

[Cole slaw in the Cholent on Shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13743/cole-slaw-in-the-cholent-on-shabbos)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: Tough one to rate because the question is (IMO) poor in that it combines two not completely analogous questions into one. The answer addresses both, pretty well (and very well considering the question quality), but I'd never Google both together. Googling them separately, I get us [right on top for cole slaw](https://www.google.com/search?q=coleslaw+chulent|cholent+bishul) and [below the fold for soup](https://www.google.com/search?q=crouton+soup+bishul). Overall +1.

Answer (score 2):

[Kiddush BeRov 'Am](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13664/kiddush-berov-am)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: +1: #1 Google hit on [my search terms](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22one+person+makes%22+%22everyone|everybody+makes%22+kiddush|kidush); we've good answers.

Answer (score 1):

[Papaya - Ha'Etz or Ha'Adama?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13863/papaya-haetz-or-haadama)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: according to anna, it's +1, as our answer is on page 2 when searching for "bracha on papaya" and is good. However, there is a full page of answers answering perfectly before, so if I were searching, I wouldn't have found it,

Comment: Par: +0. Good answer, but not sure I'd call it "stellar", and, as @ShmuelBrin notes, it's on [page 2](https://www.google.com/search?q=bracha|beracha+papaya).

Comment: The question is not, "what bracha do you make on papaya?". For that, there are a hundred perfectly valid answers available. The question is, "_why_ is there a dispute on its bracha?" For that, we are the #2 hit on google, and the simplest and most readable answer. +1

Comment: @msh210 @ ShmuelBrill ^^^ courtesy pings

Answer (score 1):

[How come Sepharadim say "Boreh peri haGEFen" but "Shelo Asani AVed"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13709/how-come-sepharadim-say-boreh-peri-hagefen-but-shelo-asani-aved)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: +1: #3 hit on [my search terms](http://www.google.com/search?q=hagafen+hagefen+%22asani+aved|eved%22+aved+eved); decent answer, better than the first two hits.

Comment: low on mine: <hagafen hagefen  aved eved>

Comment: @msh210 the interesting thing is that when I click that link, the only result is Shmuel's comment above!

Comment: My search terms (why hagefen but aved) show us as the top answer. +1

Comment: @HodofHod (re "the interesting thing"), me, too, now. When I wrote the above comment, though, I was being truthful. I don't know what's going on with Google.

Answer (score 0):

[Seared Sushi Bishul Yisroel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13779/seared-sushi-bishul-yisroel)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: Oddly, Google, on [my search terms](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bishul+yisrael|yisroel|akum%22+sear|blacken+sushi), doesn't show any useful pages, even though our page should show up among those results! Not sure what's up with Google. But I guess that's a -1, then.

Comment: @msh210 the problem seems to be that google doesn't recognize "sear" as a synonym for "seared". Switch the two, and we're the first hit. Also, we're the first useful hit for [seared sushi kosher]. +1

Comment: @HodofHod, it certainly used to recognize such variants (outside of quotation marks).

Comment: @msh210 It still does, but it's imperfect (surprise, surprise). This seems to be one example where their synonym database is lacking.

Answer (score -1):

[The number of Challot on Shabbat and salt](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13724/the-number-of-challot-on-shabbat-and-salt)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: Tough one to rate, because the "salt" part of the question was (as noted in answers) based on a mistaken hypothesis; thus, Googling for it messes up the results (whether from our site or from others). But [my search terms](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lechem+mishne|mishneh%22+salt+reason+day+night+man|mon|manna) showed our site *nowhere* among the results, and the first result was a nice answer elsewhere. -1.